# Calculate remaining time between current time and 12am

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I want to get the time difference from the current time and 12am of next day.

For Example :-

Current time is 5:00:00 pm.

So the time difference from 00:00:00 (12 am ) next day will be 07:00:00 hours.

So far I've tried mysql's `TIMEDIFF, date_sub` functions but it didn't provide the desired results.

A help is highly appreciated.

**P.S** - I'm using mysql 5.6.3

Comment: This really has nothing to do with sql, which is intended for the storage and retrieval of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `24:00:00` instead of `00:00:00` to get desired result:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', '17:00:00')
-- 07:00:00
```

The TIME datatype can represent values greater than/equal to 24 hours, even negative values.

Comment: Thank you so much @salman for replying , this works out for me perfectly however with a little modification, As I want to get the difference from **current -time** which is - **SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00', CURRENT_TIME());** , much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL TIMEDIFF() function returns the difference between two time or datetime values.

The way it works is, you provide the two values to compare, and TIMEDIFF() subtracts the second value from the first, then returns the result as a time value.

The syntax goes like this:

```
    TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

Where expr1 and expr2 are the two values to compare. The return value is expr2 subtracted from expr1.

In your case, you can use the date with the arguements.

```
    SELECT TIMEDIFF('2021-01-01 10:35:25', '2021-01-02 00:00:00');
```

Also note that the time data type can only be in the range -838:59:59 to 838:59:59. Therefore, the following doesn’t work:

```
    SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000-01-01 10:35:25', '2021-01-01 10:35:25');
```

For reference, please visit:

https://database.guide/timediff-examples-mysql/